# Search query with id

Tags: mysql, sql

This are my tables:

Part table:

```
Part_id name
1       Case
2       Pen
3       Chicken
```

(Between table)table:

```
 Part_id product_id
 2       10
 2       10
 3       30
```

Product table:

```
 product_id       Name
 10               Phone
 20               Camera
 30               Mouse
```

I want to search on the product name and get the product name back + the linked part name. But if i search on part name i want to get the part name and product name back.

I don't know how to  join the tables but don't know how to preform an search like that.

```
Select part.name, product.name 
from part
left join betweentable on part.part_id = betweentable.part_id
```

But i don't know how to join the next table. And than search to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I understand this correctly... you have a name, which may be a product name or a part name, and you want to search for that, and return the linked parts if it's a product, or the linked products if it's a part.

If that's what you're asking, you can use the following query:

```
Select part.name, product.name 
from part
left join betweentable on part.part_id = betweentable.part_id 
left join product on product.id = betweentable.product_id
where part.name = <input_name>
union
Select part.name, product.name 
from product
left join betweentable on product.id = betweentable.product_id 
left join part on part.part_id = betweentable.part_id 
where product.name = <input_name>;
```

< input_name > is the name you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an other join:

```
Select part.name, product.name 
from part
left join betweentable on part.part_id = betweentable.part_id 
left join product on product.id = betweentable.product_id
```